# Strange result strrpos php

Tags: php, strpos

i'm retrieving strange result using `strrpos`

```
$link = "www.mysite.com/?_vc=1&_pgn=2";
$position = strrpos($link,"&_pgn=");
echo "<br/>".$position;
```

result is black page.

if i change pattern in strrpos like:

```
$position = strrpos($link,"&");
```

it give me value

```
21
```

What is the problem? can you help me?

Comment: I assume when you say the result is a "black" page, you mean a blank page. Also, the "changed" pattern that gives you the value is exactly the same as the original. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: 21 seems to be the right position.

Comment: i don't see how you changed it, for me your code works

Comment: i am not able to find any change in the pattern, what have u actually changed?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, those two calls to strrpos are exactly the same?

Comment: Your code works. I don't see any issue with it as long as it returns 21

Comment: sorry i changed the second pattern pls see edit

Comment: Your code is working correctly without any changes. Maybe some encoding problems in yours editor?

Comment: @Mfix $position = strrpos($link,"&_pgn="); returns you correct index? why it gives me nothing?

Comment: There are comments on [php.net/strrpos](http://uk3.php.net/strrpos) that suggest when using `strrpos`, older versions of php do not accept more than one character. Perhaps this is relevant

Comment: Most likely, the link is comming from somewhere, and it's not hardcoded in the source, and it's not the same (although it can look the same, but it may be &amp;_pgn=). strrpos returns false, and since you are trying to echo it, the page is blank (it would not be if you use var_dump() instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some casual googling over my morning coffee, it would seem you are still using PHP4.

> In PHP 4, strpos( ) uses an entire string as a needle, whereas
>   strrpos( ) limits the needle to a single character. If you pass
>   strrpos( ) a string of more than one character, it silently uses only
>   the first character.
>
> In PHP 5, strrpos( ) and strripos( ) now behave identically to strpos(
>   ) , in that they find strings instead of just the first character.

Hence why your code appears to work for most people, yet not for you. I found this [here](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.350.1.110/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The code works and returns

```
<br/>21
```

Try turning errors on (if off) to see why you are getting blank page 
it must be some other code or a typo

error settings

```
ini_set('display_errors','on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```